# Will my Rewards get deducted by keeping a cat

Tags: halal-haram, qiraat, doubts, halal-certification, pets

Assalamualaikum ,
Brothers And Sisters.

It is said that keeping a pet dog will keep the Angels away and deduct the rewards from the prayers.

But I didn't get exact research about keeping any other animal

I am really curious about cats.
Surely it's said that cats are admired for it's cleanliness and was loved by Prophet Muhammed.
But can I keep it as a pet ?
Is it allowed ?..... Or will my rewards get deducted for it too?..

Comment: Wa Alaikum As Salam. No, that only applies to dogs. Cats are fine to keep.

Answer (score 1):

Waalaikumsalam,

Abu Talha reported Allaah's Prophet (sallAllaahu alayhi wa sallam) having said:

> "Angels do not enter a house in which there is a dog or a picture." **[HR.**
> **al-Bukhari and Muslim]**

To answer your question, other animals that does not belong to the following categories **are allowed** to be taken care as a pet :

1. Animals that cause harm or damage, such as snakes, lions and tigers. The proposition is the hadith of the Prophet sallallaahu 'alaihi wa sallam:

> "No harm to yourself and others." **[HR. al-Hakim]**

2. Animals that are basically haraam to eat, such as pigs (QS. 2: 173).
3. Animals that are endangered and protected by law. It is not advisable for these animals to be kept at home, but given to zoo, wildlife or government protection (QS 4: 83).